# Yellow poly gas pipe to copper tubing transition

Tags: pipe, gas

I need to run a liquid propane gas line from my tank to my house.  The house and tank connections are currently copper tubing.  I was thinking of using yellow poly pipe for this run, but I haven't been able to find the proper transition pieces from the yellow pipe to copper.  What kind of transition fittings could I use?

Additionally, this could be a dumb idea, so feel free to tell me that also.

Here is the yellow poly pipe: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B0759LPYSZ/ref=ox_sc_act_image_2?smid=A28LU3M6V82A2C&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0759LPYSZ)

Comment: What is wrong with the transition linked from the product page? https://www.amazon.com/Underground-Yellow-Poly-Pipe-Transition/dp/B0759DBVWH/ref=pd_aw_sim_60_1/137-8293031-8126866?_encoding=UTF8

Comment: I take it your propane supplier and AHJ are cool with both piping materials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly use polyethylene pipe. There are some considerations that need to be made

1. It must be to code.
2. The branch of pipe you are referring to is called the yard line. It's in between the first stage and second stage regulator. It's often considered the property of the utility unless you own the tank.
3. For code compliance all polyethylene pipe must be buried as its not uv resistant. My code states a minimum of 18" and a minimum of 24" under driveways and walkways. A trace wire must also be attached.

**This is what a complete set looks like**

[image]

[www.rphdistributorsltd.com](http://www.rphdist.com/Gas-Lines.page)

The picture shows more than what you would require. I picked this one to give you an idea of what is available. Specifically [this riser](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07C34BM9T) is what you are looking for. Common brands are

- Gastight
- Perfection Pipe
- Home-Flex

Comment: Can poly be used for propane?  I remember there being a reason that iron was used for natural gas and copper for propane.

Comment: Poly, iron and copper are suitable for both NG and propane. Copper flows less due to it being measured outside diameter vs. iron measured inside diameter. Propane's higher pressure and roughly three times heat content allows for a much smaller diameter line compared to NG. So copper becomes practical. I can gas up a propane house in fractions of the time because all I need is a flaring tool, a couple handfuls of fittings and a roll or two of 1/2 and 5/8 copper. That's not going to happen on NG. Threader, wrenchs, crates of fittings and much larger pipe.